# Keyboard shortcut to respond to notification?

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, notification

I am wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to respond to a notification.

E.g. you get a notification that a chat messages has been recevied.

Press ??? and it will open the chat window.

Same sort of thing with email, wifi connected etc.

Comment: This is an example question i a very good thing to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No unfortunately not - notify-osd is specifically designed not to be interactive so there is no way you can interact with a notification at all, including clicking it, or activating it with a key binding etc - see the [NotifyOSD wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) and in particular the section on rationale.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is...

If I understand you correctly and you use pidgin for example, then the notification icon will turn green when you received a chat message in pidgin. So just go <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, and that will select chat/mail notification.

So then you can select the person that contacted you and reply.

Comment: Super + M opens the Dash music lense. Also your answer would much rather be a comment to alexmurray's earlier answer.